# Getting error while generating an unique auto Generated Serial Number for a day using stored procedure in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, generator, serial-number

I want to create a procedure which would create a serial number using a stored procedure.

I have three tables:

Table 1:

```
create table ItemTypes
(
    ItemTypeID int not null primary key,
    ItemType varchar(30)
)
```

Table 2:

```
create table ItemBatchNumber
(
     ItemBatchNumberID int not null primary key,
     ItemBatchNumber varchar(20),
     ItemType varchar(30),
)
```

Table 3:

```
create table ItemMfg
(
    ManufactureID int not null primary key,
    ItemBatchNumberID int foreign key references ItemBatchNumber(ItemBatchNumberID),
    MfgDate datetime 
)
```

For each Item Type there are several Item batch number.

Now, first 3 digit of serial no is xyz. 4 digit of serial no should be Item Type(e.g if Item type is 'b' then serial no should be xyzb).

5 digit of serial no should be like this:

In a day, for first Item batch number of a Item type, 5th digit should be 1 and it will remain 1 for that day.For the next different Item batch number it should be 2 and it will remain 2 for that day.

Same rule applied for next day and other item type.

e.g suppose 'b' Item Type has 3 Item batch number WB101,WB110,WB231. If today someone select WB110(Item batch number) of 'b' Item Type first then Serial No should be xyzb1 and it will remain xyzb1 for today for WB110. Now if someone select WR101 next then Serial No should be xyzb2 for today. Tomorrow which Item batch number of 'b' Item type will be selected first, for that batch number and that type serial no should be xyzb1. Same rule applied for other item type.

I have tried till now:
I have created a new table and stored data into that table and tried to check with columns of that new table.

```
Create table Gen_SN
(
ItemType varchar(10),
ItemBatchNumber varchar(10),
SerialNumber varchar(10),
mfgDate datetime
)


 Create procedure Gen_SerialNumber
    (
         @IitemType char(1),
         @ItemBatchNumber varchar(30),
         @Date datetime,
         @SerialNumber varchar(10) out,
         @fifthDigit int=0 out
    )
    AS
    BEGIN 
        SET  @IitemType =
             (
                SELECT ItemType 
                FROM   ItemBatchNumber 
                WHERE  ItemBatchNumber=@ItemBatchNumber
             )

        DECLARE @SerialNumber1 VARCHAR(20)
        SET @SerialNumber1 = 'xyz' + '' + @IitemType + ''
                            + CAST((SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ItemBatchNumber)
                                    FROM ItemBatchNumber
                              WHERE ItemType = @IitemType) AS VARCHAR(10))
        SET @fifthDigit = SUBSTRING(@SerialNumber1, 5, 1)

        IF EXISTS(SELECT SerialNumber FORM Gen_SN WHERE SerialNumber=null or         SerialNumber!=@SerialNumber)
                          SET @fifthDigit=1
        IF EXISTS(SELECT mfgDate,ItemBatchNumber FROM Gen_SN WHERE mfgDate=@Date and ItemBatchNumber=@ItemBatchNumber)
                          SET @fifthDigit=1
                     ELSE 
                          SET @fifthDigit=@fifthDigit+1

    SET @SerialNumber=('xyz'+''+@ItemType+''+cast(@fifthdigit as varchar(2)))
INSERT INTO Gen_SN VALUES(@ItemType,@ItemBatchNumber,@SerialNumber,@Date)
END
```

I am new to SQL Server. 4rth digit of SN is generated correctly from my code. I am facing problem on how to increment the value of fifth digit checking with dates when next different item batch number of a same item type or different item type is used.

I am also getting an error while executing that procedure.

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'a' to data type int.

Please let me know how can I solve it.

Comment: All your ID types are INT i.e. numeric and you are trying to store xyz-some-number in there? You need to change your datatype to alphanumeric.

Comment: I have edited my question. Please go through it. Still expecting result is not coming out. Please help

Answer (score 1):

`@fifthdigit` is declared as an integer.  When you do:

```
Select 'SN: xyz' + '' + @IitemType + '' + @fifthDigit
```

Because one of the arguments is numeric, the `+` is interpreted as addition -- and the addition is failing on strings.

So, either declare `@fifthdigit` as a string or do an explicit conversion:

```
Select 'SN: xyz' + '' + @IitemType + '' + cast(@fifthDigit as varchar(255))
```

Note:  there might be other places in the code that have similar problems.

Comment: Well spotted I had to format that SQL statement first. Completely OCD about syntax so had to fix that first.

Comment: I have edited my question. Please go through it. Still expecting result is not coming out. Please help.